# Springsource Tool Suite unable to find sites

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm trying to configure SpringSource Tool Suite 2.7.1.RELEASE

If I try to install a plugin, `Help -> Install New Software...` I get the following error, even though the URLs are correct.

[image: sts error message]

Here is the error log:
[image]

On the suspicion that this could be related to a proxy, I have put in the following proxy settings:

[image]

but none of the variations that I've tried here have made a difference. Any ideas? Any workarounds?

If there is a forum more appropriate for STS question, I'd really appreciate that info.

Comment: did you check the error log for more details??

Comment: Sorry, should have included that the first time.

Comment: likewise here.. any guidance on the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: My workaround was to upgrade to a newer STS, which seemed to work. No promises.

Comment: I have downloaded the 3.7 and update zip file. Is it the newest?

Answer (score 1):

Please ask a question on the STS forum:
http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite

Comment: where is it? Could you post here the exact url?

Comment: Does this url not work for you?  http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?32-SpringSource-Tool-Suite

Comment: I was not talking about a specific thread.  As I mentioned in my answer, if you have a question, you should ask there.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with SpringSource Tool Suite 2.9.1.RELEASE trying to install a maven m2e plugin.  Turns out the latest version of AVG (2012 Free) Virus Scan was blocking the update process from being able to download/create the jars needed to run the update.  Temporarily disabled virus protection and updates worked.